# c# mvc - razor not rendering html but displaying it raw

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following string in my table column

```
<p>img page&nbsp;<img alt="" src="/fileman/Uploads/Images/Capture.PNG" style="height:255px; width:365px" /></p>
```

which I display like so in the view:

```
<dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Body)
        </dt>
```

However I get the actual string as the output, `<p>` tags do not actually become `<p>` tags and the `img` is not rendered.

How to make it render as html?

Comment: use `@Html.Raw()`

Comment: Thanks! @Html.Raw(Model.Body)

Comment: For future seekers, this question has a specific answer that the previous question does not: do not use a lambda for you model. For example: `@Html.Raw(DisplayFor(m=>m.column))` will fail. You literally want `@Html.Raw(Model.column)`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as intended

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `@model.Body` has the html with the `<p>` tags in, using `@Html.Raw(model.Body)` should give you your desired result.

Comment: That gives me an error, "model does not exist in current contextt"

Comment: Does it give you the error when you remove the @ from model.body?

Comment: Model needs to be upercase `@Html.Raw(Model.Body)`